Is there a way to fix image upload for Facebook app verification?
UPD. Done, used latest Firefox w/o extra plugins
I need to create one app into Facebook messenger. Developers facebook page (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/.../app-review/submissions/current-request/?business_id=...) (ids hidden of course) ask to add a photo. But photo does not upload in any way, tried several formats and images as well as several image resolutions. Using the latest browser Chrome with Windows 11, if it is important. Please help.

